# Will there be any issues if the rpm's are built on CentOS and deployed on RHEL?

Tags: centos, redhat-enterprise-linux

We are planning to build the rpm's on CentOS(as the repo is in CentOS) and deploy it on RHEL nodes. Would like to know your suggestion on the same and if any one has encountered any issues while doing the same.

Answer (score 0):

This is by definition (and in real-world) possible. These OSes are binary compatible and also have same base packets available.
In fact epel for example also does this as many other repos for EL do. Only the version of system and dependencies matters here in normal case.